# need advise on email modules in laravel 5.3, saving html mail body as view or store to DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

i am newbie to laravel, i want to develop email module in laravel it can be used thoughout the application.

say, ecommerce website it will send mail while registration. while order the goods, etc,

i need an advice regarding

1.is saving html mail body in DB is good over creating mail body as view?
2.which laravel functionality is good to implement sending mail module thoughout the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create mail body as a view. It makes no sense to save it in the DB and call it every time you need to send an email. The mail body is an static element, it will not change very often. The only things that need to be updated every time you send an email are the variables you attach with that email. Laravel provides this functionality out of the box with [Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail). Therefore to send an email while ordering the goods for example you need first to collect the data for that particular order. Let's say:

```
$data = [
        'name'          => $request->name,
        'email'         => $request->email,
        'phone'         => $request->phone,
        'body_message'  => $request->message,
        'item'          => $item
    ];
```

- In this example I am collecting the date from a form. The item element can be stored in the Session while shopping or using any other approach.
- IMPORTANT: I used the index 'body_message' in that array. You cannot use 'message'. I had this problem before, it is a protected name.

Then to send the message just call the Mail::send() method, something like this:

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.your_view'],
        $data
        , function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->from('YourEmailAddress', 'YourCompanyName');
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Your Order in YourCompanyName');
        });
```

Then in the view you can include the data stored in that array using this syntax:

```
{!! $body_message !!}
```

You also need to have a look to the link I provided about Laravel Mail. You need to install extra packages, use a Mail Driver, configure the config/mail.php file and possible store some information in your .env file.

I hope this helps at least as an starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the info. answer accepted. 
by the way what you think about mailable class

Comment: I know it is a new feature brought by L5.3, however I didn't try it yet but it seems very straight forward and you will get everything you need out of the box. Give it a try!